# QGIS SCP SAGA Close gaps with stepwise resampling

Tags: qgis, classification, saga, scp

I am working with QGIS 3 and classifying images in Indonesia. Indonesia has a high cloud coverage. I started with classifying a Sentinel 2 image with the SCP Tool and got my classification output.

I classified clouds and cloud-shadows into MC ID 0 named unclassified.

Now I want to work with the `Close gaps with stepwise resampling` from SAGA processing toolbox and set its Resampling method to Nearest Neighbour.

After interpolation, I have thousands of different classes instead of my 8 classes. 1; 1,001, 1,002,...

How can I combine the classes again, otherwise land change analysation is not working.

[image]

Comment: Are the size of gaps in your raster big? Then the tool `Close gaps with stepwise resampling` may not work as expected, and `Close gaps with spline` is recommended. As a separate note, `Shrink and Expand` would work better for categorical (integer) dataset.